# Record participants video stream individually in jitsi-meet

Tags: webrtc, recording, video-recording, jitsi, jitsi-meet

I’m using jitsi for one of our requirement. I have followed quick installation steps to config and install jitsi. I am also using https://jitsi.github.io/handbook/docs/dev-guide/dev-guide-iframe to create room along with some config changes.

One of our requirement is to record the video of participants individually. Basically saving each participants video stream. As of I know Jibri records the whole conference session but we need video streams of participants separately. There was a library which has been archived now Jirecon. I used a enhanced version of it, but was not successful.

Please can anybody help on which approach to follow and how to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Jibri joins as like participant and records the conference this mean you cannot record each participant via Jibri.

You can try client side recording and after that you can upload the file wherever you want. You can check RecordRTC( https://github.com/muaz-khan/RecordRTC ).  But i am not sure about iFrame(you mention about "external_api.js"). You can try.

If you have own instance of jitsi, better way of implementation is instance web project(/usr/share/jitsi/meet). create a js file, develop client side recording and load the file into index.html. And trigger the recording actions via iframe postMessage .

I am not sure but if your purpose is sharing the media files to other participants, you can use jibri and save into local server tempMedia folder and share from there for a while.

Comment: we have setup our own instance. we are thinking of bandwidth usage of user in order to do it at the client side as jitsi-meet have already established such bandwidth. So, searching if that could be possible from jitsi server side itself. Please suggest.